# Dynamically add different classes to colapsable tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have a simple for loop that loops through my objects and prints them in a collapsible tab but because I have more than one tab printed I need to change the classes of each tab so that they dont interfere between eachother.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to change so that every tab has different id "collapseNumber" and a href that corresponds to that class "#collapseNumber". So that all my printed tabs have classes like "collapse1, collapse2, collapse3, ...."

The problem right now is that the loop prints the same tab with id of "collapse1" and I want the others to have their own so that when I open the first tab the others don't do that aswell.

Comment: you can use loop counter or index append with id.. you tried it?

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried so far JS-wise... So far, you've just copied and pasted a snippet from BootStrap's accordion directly and am expecting us to write out your script from scratch?

Comment: I dont have any code only the for loop which loops try all of my products. I will try to do index append with id

Comment: have you tried with appending ids?does it work?

Comment: A bit heated there...

Anyway, I also am with David, it's difficult to tell you how to fix it without having some idea of how you are generating this code. Is it generated on the client side with Javascript or server side with PHP for example. If it is generated with Javascript on client side, then the text is not 'printed'. 

I am just going to assume it's with jQuery, so, in your for loop, you could make it add the href and id using the iterator variable you are using in the loop. If it's "i" then add it into the ID and HREF tag in the appropriate format?

Comment: I am not asking you guys to fix my code I am asking for somebody to tell me how these things are being done obviously I don't have a clue: here is my loop if that would even help:  for(var i=0, product; product = data.location.availableProducts[i]; i++);

Comment: Well, in the part of that loop which adds this part into your collapsible tab '<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">', add a string escape so that you do this instead '<div id="collapse'+ i +'" class="panel-collapse collapse in">' then in the other part '<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse'+ i +'">'. Without seeing the part that actually generates the code that is being put onto the page, I cannot help you further, there just are way too many possibilities how it could be done.